# Why shouldn't I add a tag to increase visibility?

Tags: discussion, tagging

I recently had my edit suggestion rejected when I tried to add a tag to someone else's post.  I grant that my new tag didn't "help to define the topic of the question," (The body of the post itself does this quite well most of the time, and I confess I didn't even know this was a purpose of tagging.) but should I really not add an appropriate tag that would increase the visibility of a good question to people who can answer it?  This seems odd but I trust there's a good reason for it.

For context, I tried to add differential-geometry to this post [One parameter subgroup that leaves every compact set is a proper map](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1033490/one-parameter-subgroup-that-leaves-any-compact-is-a-proper-map)

Comment: [Here](http://math.stackexchange.com/review/suggested-edits/306807) is link to the review in question.

Comment: There will always be edge cases, at least for most rules.  You want "to increase visibility", so put yourself in the mind of someone who searches for that tag:  Is the tagged Question going to be signal or noise?  So the dictum in the rejection template singles out the issue of whether the tagged topic "describe[s] what the question is *about*, not just what it *contains*".

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Your suggested edit was good. The review system is not perfect; nothing is. In particular, tag-only edits tend to be judged more harshly than other edits.

I added the tag.